# Printing "count" of even numbers while-loop with if

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am suppose to be able to complete the following in Python...

> Fill in the blanks to complete the function “even_numbers(n)”. This function should count how many even numbers exist in a sequence from 0 to the given “n” number, where 0 counts as an even number.  For example, even_numbers(25) should return 13, and even_numbers(6) should return 4.
>
> ```
> def even_numbers(n):
>    count = 0
>    current_number = 0
>    while ___ # Complete the while loop condition
>        if current_number % 2 == 0::
>            ___ # Increment the appropriate variable
>        ___ # Increment the appropriate variable
>    return count
>    
> print(even_numbers(25))   # Should print 13
> print(even_numbers(144))  # Should print 73
> print(even_numbers(1000)) # Should print 501
> print(even_numbers(0))    # Should print 1
> ```

I've tried every variation I can think of for changing every variable I can think of. I have referenced the coursework (I've been stuck on this question for a solid week and counting), I have searched Stack Overflow and found multiple variations to reference not exactly what I need to do (and most well advanced from where I am learning right now... even though they solve the problem they don't...I tried them anyway hoping a light bulb would go off but it hasn't).

I've been trying to get the print(even_numbers(#)) sections to match up... make the script work.

Is there anyone who can explain this to me without giving away the answer outright? I really want to understand where I am going wrong and why. I am a complete novice and mostly self taught from books.

Attempts (a few of them)

---

```
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_numbers = 0
    while n > current_numbers: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_numbers % 2 == 0:
            count = count + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
        else:
            current_numbers = current_numbers + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count
    
print(even_numbers(25))   # Should print 13
print(even_numbers(144))  # Should print 73
print(even_numbers(1000)) # Should print 501
print(even_numbers(0))    # Should print 1

Evaluation took more than 5 seconds to complete.
                Please try again with a simpler expression.
```

---

```
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_number = 0
    while n > current_number: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_number % 2 == 0:
           count = count + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
        else:
            current_number = current_number + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count

print(even_numbers(25))   # Should print 13
print(even_numbers(144))  # Should print 73
print(even_numbers(1000)) # Should print 501
print(even_numbers(0))    # Should print 1

Evaluation took more than 5 seconds to complete.
                Please try again with a simpler expression.
```

---

```
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_numbers = 1
    while n > current_numbers: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_numbers % 2 == 0:
           count = count + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
           current_numbers = current_numbers + 1
        else:
           current_numbers = current_numbers + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count
    
print(even_numbers(25))   # Should print 13
print(even_numbers(144))  # Should print 73
print(even_numbers(1000)) # Should print 501
print(even_numbers(0))    # Should print 1

12
71
499
0
```

Comment: *"where 0 counts as an even number"* - I'm appalled they said that. Can anyone find a definition of "even number" where 0 is ***not*** even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting even numbers from `current_number == 0` to `current_number == n`, so you should initialize `current_number` to `0`, and the loop condition should be `current_number <= n`.

Modifying your third attempt, the code should be:

```py
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_number = 0
    while n >= current_number: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_number % 2 == 0:
           count = count + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
           current_number = current_number + 1
        else:
           current_number = current_number + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count
    
print(even_numbers(25))   # Should print 13
print(even_numbers(144))  # Should print 73
print(even_numbers(1000)) # Should print 501
print(even_numbers(0))    # Should print 1
```

Finally, the `current_number = current_number + 1` line is in both `if` and `else` branch, so you can extract it out and eliminate `else`:

```
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_number = 0
    while current_number <= n: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_number % 2 == 0:
            count += 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
        current_number += 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! These answers helped greatly and I wrote them down for future reference (hopefully to avoid a week of pulling my hair out...)

Answer (score 2):

There's no `else:` in the code in the assignment. You need to increment `current_number` every iteration, not just when the number is odd. Otherwise you'll get stuck on the same number when it's even. So you should not add an `else:` block.

Also, the results should count `n` if it's even, so the condition should be `current_number <= n`.

```
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_number = 0
    while current_number <= n: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_number % 2 == 0::
            count += 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
        current_number += 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your last attempt. You need to start `current_number` at 0 and make sure to use a greater than or equal to sign:

```py
def even_numbers(n):
    count = 0
    current_numbers = 0
    while n >= current_numbers: # Complete the while loop condition
        if current_numbers % 2 == 0:
           count = count + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
           current_numbers = current_numbers + 1
        else:
           current_numbers = current_numbers + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
    return count
    
print(even_numbers(25))   # Should print 13
print(even_numbers(144))  # Should print 73
print(even_numbers(1000)) # Should print 501
print(even_numbers(0))    # Should print 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This got me the right answer

```
def even_numbers(n):
   count = 0
   current_number = 0
   while current_number <= n:
       if current_number % 2 == 0:
           count += 1
       current_number += 1
   return count
   
print(even_numbers(25))
print(even_numbers(144))
print(even_numbers(1000))
print(even_numbers(0))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This works, too, and I would absolutely submit this.

```
def even_numbers(n):
   count = 0
   current_number = 0
   while not current_number: # Complete the while loop condition
       if current_number % 2 == 0:
           count += n // 2 + 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
       current_number = 1 # Increment the appropriate variable
   return count
```